# How to bring workspace layer to one combo box and once layer selected in this attribute of this layer in other combo box

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext, ext-js

I want a layers in workspace in combo box.Once i select combo box i want attribute in selected layer to in other combo box. how can i do it. I am using geoserver, openlayers, Geoext and ext js.

Can any one just help me

my combo box code is:

```
            var simpleCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                fieldLabel: 'Select layer Name',
                displayField: 'name',
                width: 320,
                labelWidth: 100,
                store: store3,
                queryMode: 'local',
                emptyText:'Layer Selection',
                typeAhead: true,
                listeners : {
                    'select' : function(){
                        var selValW = this.getValue();

                            txtquery(selValW);
                }}
            });
```